# Application crashed on button click frequently

Tags: android, button, crash, touch

I havecustom keyboard for entering numbers,when i change focus and return back the button clicks events slow downs the application and leads to application crash.what could be the problem.In logcat i get Gc collector freed message.I tried locking multiple clicks for buttons simultaneously,but dint help.

Comment: A Logcat stacktrace will help for us..

Comment: add the logcat output it will be helpful..

Comment: post Logcat output and also some relevant code